# Hybris 1905 site problem where promotion is valid

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, rules, commerce, promotions

In Hybris 1905, I would like to define a 20 Eur discount promotion only for orders over 100Eur in electronic. For this, I select promoGroup electronicPromoGrp in the promotion. But the promotion is also active on the Apparel site. What is the reason?

Comment: How are you defining your promotions ? Via "Adaptive Search" perspective?

Comment: I'm creating promotion rules in backoffice

Comment: Did you look over official SAP documentation ? [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/9d346683b0084da2938be8a285c0c27a/1905/en-US/309cfe6a919a4f9189f914d18ce1734f.html) is a good example for what you need. I suggest you to follow these steps if you haven't yet.